# Fail to use babel with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I want to write a simple demo by using webpack and babel, but I really cant figure out what problem is, I have webpack version 1.13.3 and after i try to install `npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-preset-es2015` or `npm install --save-dev babel-loader` I get the following errors:

```
+-- babel-core@6.18.2
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.18.0
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
```

or

```
+-- babel-loader@6.2.8
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@1 || ^2.1.0-beta
```

I have node v.6.9.1 and npm v4.0.2
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the *latest peer dependencies* of the `webpack` are installed through the `devdependencies` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#peerdependencies)

Therefore if you try to install the webpack without installing the `webpack-dev-server` it will throw an error.

Same issue is referenced [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/349)

So using the following npm command `npm install --global webpack webpack-dev-server` eliminates the warning about the webpack as well as installing it globally.

Locally the command works fine

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server
```

Comment: your method is not working, I still have problem in installing babel

Comment: check if you have tried to globally install the webpack since the global installation of the webpack is not supported or a workaround can be found in the following link  https://github.com/webpack/grunt-webpack/issues/68#issuecomment-216696078